# maximum y speed to pass through line segments with a given maximum x speed

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates, dynamic-programming

Given a sequence of line segments S<sub>i</sub>, each with coordinates X<sub>i</sub> and Y<sub>i</sub> (for each i, Y<sub>i+1</sub> is greater than Y<sub>i</sub>) and each of length b in the x direction, how can I calculate the maximum y speed to pass through all segments where you can change the x coordinate with a maximum speed of v. (For some segment sequences this may be impossible)

Here's an example (Segment Coordinates (1, 1), (5, 2), (1, 3) and length 3 (the picture shows this incorrectly for the second segment), maximum x-speed = 2):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would first sort the line segments into increasing Y values and group together segments with the same y value. I am assuming that if there are two segments with the same y value you can go through either. If this is not the case perhaps you replace them with a single segment which is their intersection and carry on as described here, or say impossible if the intersection is empty.

Looking at the difference between the far left of any line segment and the far right of any line segment, and the smallest difference between two different Y values you can compute a speed at which you can get between the furthest left value and the farthest right value in the smallest difference between two different Y values. This is a possible speed, so the minimum possible speed is somewhere between this and 0.

Now guess a speed. For this speed you will work out, at each y value, a series of intervals which are the reachable x values. Start off with all of the segments that have the smallest y value being reachable. Now consider all the groups of segments in order of increasing y value. Work out which intervals in the group of segments are reachable from the current set of intervals, given the current speed. This becomes the new set of reachable intervals. One way of working this out - not necessarily the best - is to enlarge the current set of reachable intervals by padding them to left and right with the distance that can be travelled at the current maximum speed in the y distance between the two sets of segments and then to intersect this enlarged reachable set with the new set of segments.

Now you can binary chop on the speed (starting off between 0 and the maximum speed you worked out earlier) to get an approximate idea of the speed at which the segments are just connected. In fact I think if I was much cleverer I could have described how you can pass through the segments calculating not just intervals but linear functions on intervals, which would allow you to solve the problem exactly. In fact I think this tells me that the total length of reachable segments at the last Y value is piecewise linear in the speed you choose, when the speed is over the minimum necessary speed.

But just knowing this allows you to make guesses that are better than binary chop. Using two guesses with smallest speed that works so far extrapolate using the length of the reachable segments to guess a speed which just makes the problem reachable. If the guess doesn't work, make further passes of binary chop to get a new smallest speed that works so far before trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrased, we're given several horizontal line segments `[l_i, u_i] × {y_i}` and a horizontal speed `v` and want to find the maximum vertical speed `s` such that there exist `x_i ∈ [l_i, u_i]` with `|y_i - y_{i-1}|/s ≥ |x_i - x_{i-1}|/v`, i.e., time to move horizontally is no more than time to move vertically. This problem has an LP formulation like this.

```
minimize z (intuitively, z = v/s)
subject to
l_i ≤ x_i ≤ u_i, for all i
x_i - x_{i-1} ≤ |y_i - y_{i-1}| z, for all i
x_{i-1} - x_i ≤ |y_i - y_{i-1}| z, for all i
variables
x_i, for all i
z
```

The simplex method would make quick work of this.

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying but I'm not able to make the step to an actual implementation. I would really appreciate a hint on that. Something I forgot to mention: s has to be at least 1 and all coordinates and speeds are integers.